# Writing Rules both in Firebase and in your Code

Tags: firebase-security

Firebase suggests we write security rules in both our firebase rules section online at their console for (database/storage) in addition to the rules that we have in our code (swift/java, etc). Why is this? I feel like this would be repetitive?

Answer (score 4):

This is very common in a client-server architecture.

- The server *must* validate the data to ensure that no invalid/corrupt data every gets written to the database.
- The client *should* validate the data to give the user the best experience.

Think of an example here: say that you have a travel site where the user selects the start and end date of their journey. A common validation will be that the end date cannot be before the start date. In Firebase database security rules this could be:

```
{
  "journeys": {
    ".validate": "newData.child('startAt').val() > now &&
                  newData.child('endAt').val() > newData.child('startAt').val()"
  }
}
```

We did an extra check here, you can also not book travel before now. This is much simplified, but hopefully illustrates the server-side aspect.

On the client-side you'll typically show a calendar. When the user opens that calendar, you want to ensure they can't select dates before today. You'll also want to ensure that the end date can only be after the start date. If you've ever used a travel site where this last bit wasn't implemented, you'll know how annoying it it. Annoyed users go to other sites.