# (Firebase) Is there a way to get validation messages other than looking up records beforehand?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have been setting up rules for my Firebase database and I've noticed that all validation errors, be they in `.write` or `.validate` return a generic Permission Denied error.

From [this Google groups thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-angular/mtjVGl5mXbk) it seems this is intentional

> If there were more descriptive error messages, it would leak information about your security rules

In most of the ORMs I've used such as ActiveRecord, Datamapper, Sequelize, and Ecto, there's been the ability to return info on why a save failed.

I understand conceptually it's not very difficult to make my own validations layer, however it is rote and requires me to do a few things which I'd prefer not to:

1. logic is duplicated in rules and client-side app
2. i would need to look up the existing record whenever I save

So this question is not devoid of code, here's a snippet of my rules file and client side code:

*rules*:

```
  {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".validate": "
          (!data.exists())
        ",
        ".write": "
          ($uid === auth.uid)
        ",
        ".read": "
          (auth != null)
        "
      },
    },
  }
```

*save record from client (coffeescript)*:

```
store_user: (user) => new Promise (resolve, reject) => (->
  key = @build_user_key(user)
  @db.set(key, @build_user_data(user))
  .then => resolve()
  .catch (e) =>
    window.error = e
).apply app
```

If I run this, then check the value of `window.error` in the console, I see this:

```
error
Error: PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission denied
    at bundle.js:3868
    at fc (bundle.js:3707)
    at Ah (bundle.js:3868)
    at bundle.js:3863
    at bundle.js:3825
    at Ag.g.wd (bundle.js:3826)
    at og.wd (bundle.js:3816)
    at Yf.Xf (bundle.js:3814)
    at ag (bundle.js:3798)
    at WebSocket.Ia.onmessage (bundle.js:3797)
```

In this case I know for sure that `".validate": "(!data.exists())"` is the cause of the failure since I'm trying to create a user that already exists. But I have no way to reflect that knowledge to my client-side Javascript without looking up the record before I try and create it.

Is it really the best option to look up the record before every save? I've heard that one should "never trust the client" and besides, clients could surely deduce my db structure by looking at the source code. On the other hand, I recognize there are situations when leaking db details is bad, such as if I have a list of admin emails, I don't want to leak those out.

Comment: If you want to prevent getting an error when the node already exists, use a transaction. Aside from that, I'm not really sure what you're asking here.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen the question is how I should deal with the inability to get specific validation errors. And whether or not there is a better way than the approach I've outlined (duplicating validation logic in rules + client, and looking up records before save).

Comment: It is common to have validation logic in both client and server. The client has logic to prevent the user from entering invalid data, the server has code that ensures data validity. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37867476/writing-rules-both-in-firebase-and-in-your-code/37870212#37870212

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen That is true. I guess It's just something I'm a little lazy about; I've always preferred to display server-generated validation errors.

Comment: If you show a server-generated error message after the user submits data, you've already lost the fight for a good user experience. For the best experience, prevent that the user reaches a state where they have invalid data. If you do that, the only users who hit the server-side validations are malicious users (and a potential coding mistake) in which case it's totally fine to show the server-side error message from Firebase.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen ok thanks for your help; i'll mark the other as duplicate

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thought about this a little more - despite possibly being bad UX, receiving specific validation messages helps a lot as a developer and it would be useful if there were a way to turn this on in dev mode.

Comment: There isn't any possibility for that right now. I recommend you file [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/)